# How can I use Lambda Expressions in Java

Tags: java

How can I use something like this (Lambda Expression) in Java with JDK7 ?

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
```

I am trying to pass this method a where clause to filter the select statement, in C# I can use Lambda expressions and I am searching for a solution to do this in my Java project.

```
public List<TEntity> Get() {
    List<TEntity> result = emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery(ClassName + ".findAll").getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

This is my Method and i would like to pass a where clause tot this method.

Comment: Java doesn't support lambdas. Anonymous inner classes provide somewhat similar functionality. Perhaps if you describe what the problem you are trying to solve using a lambda, we can give alternative solutions which are more appropriate in Java.

Comment: Use [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) it will run in your JVM and compile bytecode 100% compatible with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C(sharp) person, but isn't that just the equivalent of:

```
Iterable<Entity> get();
Iterable<Entity> get(Expression<Func<Entity, Boolean>> filter);
```

Follow up to your edit: I don't know the .NET library, but a filtering in Java would look something like:

```
public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean matches(T obj);
}
...
public List<Entity> get(Predicate<Entity> filter) {
    List<Entity> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entity obj : ...blah...) {
        if (filter.matches(obj)) {
            filtered.add(obj);
         }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

In the current verbose syntax that would called like:

```
List<Entity> entities = thing.get(new Predicate<>() {
    public boolean matches(Entity obj) {
        return obj.isX() && obj.isY();
    }
});
```

A more concise syntax with random changes to semantics should be added in Java SE 8, along with library additions.

Comment: And How can i call this Method i mean what i have to pass to the Get Method now?

Answer (score 4):

Lambda expressions are part of Java 8 (see [JSR 335](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/)), so you're out of luck with JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

lamabda-functions   will be  added in Java 8. read more:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas (also known as closures) are the biggest and most awaited language change in the whole Java 8 release. A lambda expression is an anonymous function. Simply put, it's a method without a declaration, i.e., access modifier, return value declaration, and name.

read more http://www.onsandroid.com/2014/11/java-lambda-expression.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is : **How can I use Lambda Expressions in Java?** (With JDK 7)

Simple answer which I know is :**interfaces and implemention of anonymous.
 classes.**

Lambda expressions is a way of passing a block of code to a method.
We use to do this in previous version JDK7 and below too,
To understand this you need to have an understanding of interfaces and of implementing anonymous classes.

Now for detail understanding with example I **strongly** recommend this tutorial,
[Basic Lambda Expressions](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/whats-new-in-java-8-lambda-expressions.html)

This link will give you idea how it(passing code) was done before JDK7 and below and how its done now JDK8